# Printing with multiple delimiters

Tags: linux, bash

Im using this script

```
    #!/bin/bash

    echo Su direccion IP es: 
    /sbin/ifconfig | grep 'inet addr:' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{print $1}'
```

which outputs a list of all of my ip addresses
but id like to add before each address the corresponding name

example

eth0: adresss1

tun0: address2

any advice? id be grateful for some explanation
i would also like to filter the lo connection if possible? thanks

Comment: `awk` can do literally all the work here -- the `grep` bits and the `cut` bits included. And I'd strongly suggest using `ip -o addr list`; `ifconfig` on Linux has been unmaintained for over a decade, and is completely unaware of numerous new features in the network stack (such as anonymous aliases, aka unlabeled secondary IPs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another `awk`:

```
ifconfig | awk -v OFS=": " -v RS= '$1!="lo" && split($0, a, /inet addr:/) > 1{
sub(/ .*/, "", a[2]); print $1, a[2]}'
```

```
eth0: 192.168.0.101
tun0: 10.1.111.123
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ip -o addr list | awk -F'[[:space:]/]+' '$3 == "inet" && $2 != "lo" { print $2 ": " $4 }'
```

Answer (score 0):

`ip r show | awk '{print $3 $1}'`

Comment: Or better `ip r | awk  '{if (NR!=1)print $3": \t"$1}'`

Answer (score 0):

I think my take on it would be this:

```
$ ip addr |
  awk '/^[0-9]+:/{print ""} 1' | 
  awk -vRS= '{for(i=1;i<NF;i++)if($i~/^inet/)print $2,$(i+1)}'
```

This uses two awk instances: the first splits records by adding blank lines, and the second to step through fields searching for addresses.

The output of this pipeline will contain one line per IP address (IPv6 included).

Note that in `ifconfig` notation, a second IP address on an interface might show up as a "sub-interface" like `eth0:0`. This notation is only useful in conjunction with `ifconfig`, which as you've seen in comments is not the recommended way to deal with modern linuces.