# Calling a command variable on Bash

Tags: linux, bash

Im having trouble calling a variable that should bring out the output of a command.

```
#!/bin/bash

ipAddresses = 'ifconfig | awk -v OFS=": " -v RS= '$1!="lo" && split($0, a, /inet addr:/) > 1{sub(/ .*/, "", a[2]); print $1, a[2]}''

echo -e "Sus direcciones IP son: \n " $(ipAddresses)
```

Appreciating any advice

Comment: What is the result/error you are getting? Also what OS are you running this on?

Comment: This question is development of previous question by the same author: [Printing with multiple delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50007931/214178).

Answer (score 0):

Replace the final `$(ipAddresses)` with `${ipAddresses}` or just `"$ipAddresses"`, but also save the output of your command using `$()`.

Check [Difference between ${} and $() in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27472808/1135424).

A basic example:

```
#!/bin/sh

OUTPUT=$(uname -a)

echo "The output: $OUTPUT"
```

Comment: still not working :/

Comment: what is the error, output? check the basic example and try to see if that works

Comment: Argh, I'm sorry, I just realized you were only referring to the final `$(ipAddresses)`. There's still no need for the brace format, but I see where you're coming from now. If you approve my edit, I can remove the downvote. It'd be great if you could address some of the other issues too though!

Answer (score 0):

Variable assignments cannot have space around the `=` in the shell. Also, you don't want single quotes there, you want either backticks or `$()`. The single quotes should only be for your awk command. Your awk is needlessly complicated as well, and you are using command substitution (`$()`) when printing, but `ipAdresses` is a variable, not a command.

Try something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

ipAddresses=$(ifconfig | sed 's/^ *//' | awk -F'[: ]' '/^ *inet addr:/{print $3}')
printf 'Sus direcciones IP son:\n%s\n' "$ipAddresses"
```

But that is really not portable. You didn't mention your OS, but I am assuming it's a Linux and the output suggests Ubuntu (I don't have `addr` after `inet` in the output of `ifconfig` on my Arch, for example).

If you are running Linux, you could use `grep` instead:

```
ipAddresses=$(ifconfig | grep -oP 'inet addr:\K\S+')
```

`ip` is generally replacing `ifconfig`, so try this instead:

```
ipAddresses=$(ip addr | awk '/inet /{print $2}')
```

or

```
ipAddresses=$(ip addr | grep -oP 'inet \K\S+')
```

Or, to remove the trailing `/N`:

```
ipAddresses=$(ip addr | grep -oP 'inet \K[\d.]+')
```

And you don't need the variable anyway, you can just:

```
printf 'Sus direcciones IP son:\n%s\n' "$(ip addr | awk '/inet /{print $2}')"
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your intention, since they are not stated, so I am trying to guess them from the script.

**Option 1**: you are trying to get IP address to into the variable `ipAddresses` and that is not happenning.

Start by changing single quotes around the long command and debug the command.

**Option 2**: you are storing a command in variable `ipAddresses` that you want to execute on the second line.

For both of the options you need to use the the value of the variable through `$ipAdresses` on the second line.
Also fix the assignment to following formart:

```
varName="value" # Note no spaces around = sign
```